How to fix the camera.smoothfollow problem (ursina)
camera.add_script(SmoothFollow()) doesn't work. here's my code:
from ursina import *

class Player(Entity):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Player, self).__init__(
            model='quad',
            scale=1,
            parent='scene',
            color=color.green
        )

        self.speed = 5



    def update(self):
        move_direction = Vec2(held_keys['d']-held_keys['a'], held_keys['w']-held_keys['s']).normalized()
        player.position += move_direction * player.speed * time.dt

app = Ursina()

player = Player()
camera.orthographic = True
camera.fov = 20
camera.add_script(SmoothFollow(target=player, speed=8, offset=[0, 0, -4]))

app.run()

i tried this script on the other entity, not camera and it works

how do you know it doesn't follow? If there is no other elements on scene then you can't see if it moves. When I add other entity which stays in place then I see that camera follows player.

what means doesn't work? Do you get error message? Show it in question (not in comments). Do you get camera in old place but player moves? Or maybe it follows but not smoothly? You have to describe it (in question) because code may works correctly on our computers.

Code works for me on Linux - camera follows player.
The only problem is because scene is empty and I can't see how it follow.
When I add other elements on scene then I see how it follows player, and other elements stay in old place.
app = Ursina()

player = Player()

e = Entity(model='cube')   # <--- other element

camera.orthographic = True
camera.fov = 20
camera.add_script(SmoothFollow(target=player, speed=8, offset=[0, 0, -4]))

app.run()

